# Python PEP-8 return value formatting

Tags: python, documentation, pep8

I'm not sure I've seen a specific answer to this, but I have a question regarding the style conventions on return values for my python docstrings.

Consider a function like:

```
def foo(ex):
    output = 2*ex
    return output
```

In PyCharm, if I made a docstring for this function, it would look like:

```
def foo(ex):
    """
    Sample text....
    :param ex: description...
    :return: description of return value
    """
    output = 2*ex
    return output
```

My question is whether or not I should **name** my return value in the docstring? i.e.

> :return: description of return value
>
> :return: **output**: description of return value

Is there a coding standard for this or is it mostly left to personal preference?

Comment: The name doesn't matter, only the object.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by randomir, the Python PEPs do not specify how the content of docstrings should be structured. However big coding projects usually have their own guidelines for docstring content, and you could adapt one of those.

Personally I like the Numpy docstring format (see [here](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard) and [here](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html)). The local name of a return value is not included in Numpy-style docstrings. The docstring for your function would look like this:

```
def foo(ex):
    """One-line function description.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ex : float
        Description of parameter.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        Description of return value.

    """
    output = 2*ex
    return output
```

Numpy-style docstrings are supported by [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html) documentation generator as well.

Answer (score 1):

Docstring conventions are actually defined in [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) (and [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) merely references it), but only the general formatting is covered, *not content*.

The content of docstrings is usually interpreted by the *Python Documentation Generator* called [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org), and in Sphinx, following [info fields](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists) exist:

> - `param`, `parameter`, `arg`, `argument`, `key`, `keyword`: Description of a parameter.
> - `type`: Type of a parameter. Creates a link if possible.
> - `raises`, `raise`, `except`, `exception`: That (and when) a specific exception is raised.
> - `var`, `ivar`, `cvar`: Description of a variable.
> - `vartype`: Type of a variable. Creates a link if possible.
> - `returns`, `return`: Description of the return value.
> - `rtype`: Return type. Creates a link if possible.

Notice the `rtype` for the **return type**.

So, you can specify the return type with `rtype`, but the actual (local) name of the object return is irrelevant.

```
def foo(x):
    """Sample text.
    :param x: parameter description
    :type x: int
    :return: description of return value
    :rtype: int
    """
    output = 2*ex
    return output
```